# How to secure a php connect file with database passwords

Tags: php, passwords, content-management-system

I want to know how to secure a php file that has the ***database connect*** passwords  (info).

Currently I have just saved the file as ***connect.php*** because it is stored locally but now I need to upload the application and make it live.

Answer (score 0):

Place the connect.php in a directory not exposed to the web.  In a "standard" installation the webserver daemon serves from `/var/www/public`, in this case place the file in `/var/www`.